# Wordpress Custom Post Type Search URL

Tags: url, post, types

Currently Wordpress produces this URL when searching for something on a website

websitename.com/?s=tools

I want to be able to have search links for a custom post type.  The search itself wont be public but I will essentially be listing links to search:

```
<a href="websitename.com/?s=[customposttypenamehere]tools">Click Here For More Tools</a>
```

this would be the url I can simply change the search query with

```
websitename.com/?s=[insert custom post type name here]tools
```

Is it possible to produce a url like above which only return results from a custom post type?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but maybe it will help others looking for something similar. The URL structure for your wordpress site should be like this: http://example.com/?s=my-search-string&post_type=custom-post-slug

All the best